# node.js restricting a route so it can be loaded with jquery but not accessable via url

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, restriction

I have a single page application that uses jquery to load html chunks in the page. There are routes setup for these chunks on my server. However if one of my routes (for example: /signIn) were typed directly after my url then that html chunk gets loaded onto the page (mySite.com/signIn).

How can I send a 404 error code for any path entered after the url but still allow the route to be called using jquery (the way it was intended)?

Thanks!

**Edit:**
Thank you for the answers! This is the code I wrote in case anyone would like to use it. It redirects any request, not made from a jquery load, to the home page. However it allows any paths with extensions to be loaded (like js and css) except if they are entered in the url, hiding your stylesheets, javascripts and images.

```
//Prevent url path entry
app.get('*', function (req, res, next) {
  //Check for extension
  if (/\.\w*$/.test(req.url)) {
    //headers['accept'] is comma separated, get the first value
    var splitPath = req.headers['accept'].split(',');
    //If first entry is text/html then it was requested in the url, Redirect!
    if ( splitPath[0] == 'text/html' ) {
      res.redirect('/');
    }
    else {
      next();
    }
  }
  //If headers['x-requested-with'] is null then it wasn’t requested by jQuery, Redirect!
  else if (req.headers['x-requested-with'] == null) {
    res.redirect('/');
  }
  else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to block any non-AJAX requests. JQuery and other libraries add the following HTTP header to ajax requests:

> X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest

You should check for this on the server side. If it does not exist, then you can return whatever status you wish.

Answer (score 0):

For data-only routes, you could add a short token to the `data` field in `$.ajax` or whatever tool you are using to make the call.

On the server side, on data routes you would check `req.body` (if using express) for the token and then send a response based upon the presence or absence.

The easiest method may simply to check for *any* token value, saving the need to validate it.

The hardest method would be for the server to generate and issue a session token to the client that would be used to grab the html template parts (or return the 404).

Comment: This would work and is basically how the X-Requested-With header works. JQuery does the job of adding a suitable token in the HTTP request headers so you don't have to, for you to filter on the server-side.

Comment: Good to know.  I don't use jQuery a ton, I'm mostly on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a typical connect- or express-based middleware, why not just handle GET and POST requests differently? Requests from the URL bar will always be GET requests, so make those return a 404 for the path specified. Then handle POST requests properly and make sure the jQuery requests are calling using POST.

Comment: Using POST would be incorrect. The correct HTTP method to use here is GET as you are GETting a resource in both cases.